# To create an update api helper funtion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

i am unable to complete this updateAction method as all the methods i try is either i have to set all the fields i am giving as input one by one and if i just replace the old action with the current actionDTO then all the other fields which i am not giving as input are also changing to null whereas i want only the fields i am giving as input to change all the other fields to remain same .
please help i have been trying to solve this since 2 days trying different different solution looking for answers couldn't find any.

```
public Actions updateAction(ActionDTO actionDTO,String actionId){
    log.info("Entering the updateAction method of ActionsManager class");

    log.info("Exiting the updateAction method of ActionsManager class");
    return actionsRepository.findById(actionIdObject).get();
}
```

or just share how to use the fields to loop through all the fields in actionDTO and change it

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an interface @Mapper ActionMapper and try it with @BeanMapping and then use it as a partialUpdate from Service.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ActionsMapper {

    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    void updateActionFromDto(ActiosnDto dto, @MappingTarget Actions actions);
}
```

//This should be implemented in ServiceImpl and also initialize ActionsMapper in constructor

```
private ActionMapper actionsMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ActionsServiceImpl(ActionsRepository actionsRepository, ActionMapper actionsMapper) {
        this.actionsRepository = actionsRepository;
        this.actionsMapper = actionsMapper;
    }

 public Actions partialUpdate(ActionsDto actionsDto, String id) {

        Optional<Actions> optionalActions = actionsRepository.findById(id);

        if (optionalActions.isPresent()) {
            Actions myActions = optionalActions.get();
            actionsMapper.updateActionFromDto(actionsDto, myActions);

            return actionsRepository.save(myActions);
        } else {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

```
public interface ActionService {

  
    Actions partialUpdate(ActionsDto actions, String id);
}
```

Comment: do we need to add a dependency to use @Mapper , if yes please can you specify which one

Comment: All you need to do is constructor autowiring and the bean Spring will then look for beans

Comment: how to do constructor autowiring

Comment: With @Autowire annotation